# Distribution of uniformly sampled points in a specific area with a Poisson distributed number of samples

Tags: uniform-distribution, poisson-distribution, sampling

Assume I have a Poisson distribution that draws the number $n$ of points to sample: $\mathcal{P}_{\lambda}(x)$. Then, I sample $n$ points from a uniform distribution $\mathcal{U}_{[0,4]}(x)$

However, in the end, I am only interested in the points in [0, 4/d], and I do not want to sample all the unnecessary points. So, my idea was to sample $\tilde{n} = \mathcal{P}_{\lambda/d}(x)$ points from $\mathcal{U}_{[0,4/d]}(x)$ or sample $n' = \mathcal{P}_{\lambda}(x)/d$ points from $\mathcal{U}_{[0,4/d]}(x)$.

Are the results equal? Can I do so?

I created a short Matlab example:

```
clc
clear all
close all

lambda_7 = 7;
num_trials = 10000;
r74 = 0;
for i = 1:num_trials
    r7(i) = 0;
    for m = 1:poissrnd(lambda_7)
        if rand(1)*4 < 1
            r7(i) = r7(i) + 1;
        end
    end
    r74(i) = poissrnd(lambda_7/4.);
    r7b(i) = round(poissrnd(lambda_7)/4.);
end
avg7 = sum(r7) / num_trials
avg74 = sum(r74) / num_trials

figure
hold on
h7 = histogram(r7)
h74 = histogram(r74)
```

It points out that both could yield the same distribution.

(Sorry for the bad title, feel free to make it more concise.)

Edit: Matlab code revised.

Answer (score 1):

Your second option of sampling $n' = \mathcal{P}_{\lambda}(x)/d$ points from $\mathcal{U}_{[0,4/d]}(x)$  should not work.  $n'$ will have the wrong distribution in general (and sometimes may not be an integer) and will not have the same distribution as $\tilde n$.

So instead  you could choose $n$ from $\mathcal{P}_{\lambda}(x)$ and then $n'$ by choosing it from the correct distribution, which is binomial with parameters $n$ and $\frac1d$, and then sample that many points from  $\mathcal{U}_{[0,4/d]}(x)$.  This will not be faster than your method for $\tilde n$ but might be easier for some people to understand.

Comment: You're right, my second idea does not work. I forgot to round, which then results in a different distribution. However, how about my first idea to sample from the Poisson distribution with $\lambda/d$? About your approach, can you explain the reason for the binomial in more detail I do not understand, sorry.

Comment: I would have thought your first method should give you what you say you want (assuming you have described that correctly - I do not understand your MATLAB code, which seems to give you a single number rather than a distribution of a number of numbers, possibly none) and should be the same as my suggestion.

Comment: You are absolutely correct. My first solution works fine. However, I think I did not formulate my question well. So, why are the results equal? Can you show that using the theory? Moreover, I will correct my matlab code.

Comment: It is easier to see the other way round: if you have integer $d$ independent Poisson random variables $\sim\mathcal{P}_{\lambda/d}(x)$ and add them up then you get a  Poisson random variable $\sim \mathcal{P}_{\lambda}(x)$.  So the reverse works too (and by a form of continuity also works if $d$ is not an integer)